# Can not send email using Python - gmail "5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted"

Tags: python, email, automation, smtp, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email using python,

1. I am certain about the inserted username and password.
2. enabled the Less secure access on Gmail.
3. enabled Unlock Captcha

still not working and this the error that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b4sm5524089wrn.12 - gsmtp')
```

Here's how I coded:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

#envirnment variables
username = '*****.gmail.com'
password = '********'

def send_mail(text='Email Body', 
              subject='Hello World',    
              from_email='Happy Dog<HappDogy.gmail.com>', 
              to_email=None, 
              html=None):
              assert isinstance(to_email, list)
              msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
              msg ['From'] = from_email
              msg ['To'] = ', '.join(to_email)
              msg ['Subject'] = subject
              
              txt_part = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
              msg.attach(txt_part)
              
              if html != None:
                html_part = MIMEText('<h1>This is working </h1>', 'html')
                msg.attach(html_part)
              
              msg_str = msg.as_string()

              #login to my smtp server
              server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
              server.ehlo()
              server.starttls()
              server.login(username, password)
              server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg_str)
              server.quit()
```

any help?

Comment: I don't know about sending emails, but `to_email=None` and then `assert isinstance(to_email, list)` seems wrong.  Also, by the error, it looks like your username and password are incorrect.  You should double check them.  Shouldn't it be `********@gmail.com` instead of `********.gmail.com`?

Comment: Are you passing username as `*****.gmail.com` or `*****@gmail.com`?

Comment: turn off 2fa on the gmail account

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now after opting out of 2fa